# Visual Studio Code Will Not Start with Failed to decrypt error

Tags: visual-studio-code

When trying to run VSC from the executable, nothing occurs. I then tried from the command line and it is giving this error using Code.exe in Windows 11:

> [10900:0302/081435.138:ERROR:os_crypt_win.cc(102)] Failed to decrypt: Key not valid for use in specified state. (0x8009000B)

I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling with the latest version 1.87 and still no luck. What else can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try: `code --log debug --verbose` and report some more details.... (Please )

Comment: Or just remove the directory `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code`, and then **re-install all your extensions**....

Comment: You do know than you can get a list of installed extensions using: `code --list-extensions` ?

Comment: @Luuk There is no c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code folder :( Also the two other commands showed nothing.

Comment: You do have a folder: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` ?   Please check if it really gone after you did do the uninstall...  then reboot, and only after that re-install.

Comment: @Luuk - I tried uninstalling, rebooting, ensuring the directories were clean (C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code && c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code,  re-installing with no luck and the same error.

Comment: I am out of options, you could report it as a bug here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions

Comment: are you on a shared network / is your user data dir on a shared network? see https://superuser.com/q/1798783/1749748

Comment: It turns out that it was a shared network, but also a user configuration change. This was on my coworkers account who got married and the roaming profile was pointing to her older last name. It still seems like it should have worked with a fresh install though.